# Any reasons to not update pip3?

Tags: python, pip

pip3 says it is not the latest version.  Since Python and pip3 were bundled with OS by Apple, I wonder whether there might be a reason to wait for Apple to update it.

Comment: No. Update it using `pythom3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize I was on here instead of the Apple stack.  (Although pip3 offered a different update command)

Comment: `pip` (`pip3`) is Python module and you can update it as any other module using `pip` (`pip3`) or `python -m pip ...` (`python3 -m pip ...`)

Comment: pip3 -V says version pip 21.2.4 but when I installed met, it said I should update to 23.x.x  However, the commands above say "Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.2.4)"